# How do we flag obstacles on an n*n chess board

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I have a 2d array chessboard. I also have another 2d array for obstacles on 2d chessboard.

```
`int[][] obstacles=({1,2}, {2,3}, {3,4});
```

I do not understand how to use these obstacles array, and flag the positions on a chessboard, such that a piece(king, queen, etc) cannot go on that position.

Comment: You're in a better position to know what this `obstacles` array means than we are. It's not as if there's some sort of well-known implementation for "flagging obstacles on a chessboard".  But given it's an array of two-number entries, there's a good chance we're looking at coordinates here: `{1,2}` could mean an obstacle at file 1, rank 2 (square a1, if you're familiar with chess notation), and so on.  Without more information, we can only speculate further.

Comment: Do you mean by _obstacle_ a chess piece of the same color?

Comment: Yes, that is correct(a1-{1,2},  b3-{2,3}, etc).

Comment: It does not matter what color it is.

Comment: In these problem, I have to calculate how many squares can the queen visit on an n*n grid, if there is an obstacle/piece, then the queen cannot move further ahead from the position of the obstacle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using an int array instead of a boolean array? Just make an 8x8 boolean array,then initialize rows 2,3,4 and 5 to false and rows 0,1,6 and 7 to true using a nested for loop with an if/else statement to switch rows between true and false. After that, when a piece tries to move to a square, you first check the value of the target square and if it's true then that means the square is already occupied and to choose a different move. If the square a piece wants to move to is open, the boolean array elements for the new square and previous square are changed to true and false respectively.